# How to get 25 points within 1 square kilometer in Arcmap

Tags: arcgis-10.0

I tried to generate 25 sampling points within  1sqkm using distance point to point is 250m but i got only 15 points not 25 points as i expected because starting point was not at the corner. The tools I used was  Creat fishnet.

Comment: Do you want to create 25 random points per fishnet polygon or 25 points across the entire study area using the vertices of the fishnet?

Comment: If it is a fishnet you want can you edit your question to show what parameter values you used, please?  You can get these by running the tool from its dialog and then using Copy As Python Snippet in the Geoprocessing Results window.

Comment: Thank you very much for your kindly help. Now I can solve my problem.